# Fire Journey Builder when Contact Object is Updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, standard-objects, field-update

In Journey Builder where the Entry Object is Contact, i have setup event criteria to fire journey upon Creation or Updating a Contact. But once activated, the journey only fires up when a Contact is Created.

Then i tried updating that Contact, but it is not being accepted in the Journey.

Journey settings is set to Re-Entry Anytime.

Is it possible to fire a journey by updating a Contact?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the api log (SFDC > Marketing Cloud tab > Configure > Initiate log, running for 1hour after activation) if the update action causes a call to marketing cloud?

Comment: @StephandePaly ive been checking the API logs it seems that update is not  firing HTTP CALLOUT|FireJourneyBuilderEvent ..no logs for particular update contact

Comment: Thought so. My next step would be to set up a second journey with the same entry criteria that only listens to update actions. The journey itself doesn't have to contain anything but a decision or random split (no matter what you split). The idea is to further narrow the possible issues and this way you can check if it is a problem with object update actions themselves.

Comment: @StephandePaly already resolve the issue in the Contact, ive update a field that will do have a boolean value everytime an edit  on contact is being made it will be flag as fieldname=true.. since my entry criteria has a value fieldname=false on JB.. meaning that particular contact has been updated.. then after entering the journey update that field again to false..so it can re-entry in the journey if that contact has been edited.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5) is a little misleading when it states: "The rule does not run when a record that previously met rule criteria is updated". Makes it sound like a record can't qualify again.

So for updated to work, the record needs to be updated from something different than the entry criteria condition, to something that equals the condition. 
For example, entry criteria is "some_number_field > 0". If the value is 1 for first entry and you change to 2, it wont trigger and re-enter. You would need to change that value to 0 to disqualify and then to 2 (or anything greater than 0) in order to qualify.

To get around this I created a new custom field as a boolean on the object. Journey entry criteria is then set to "New_Field = False". When I create the new object I set the field to "False" which enters the record into the journey. Then in the first step in the journey I set the New_Field value to "True". When I want the record triggered into the journey again I set to "False" again.

Comment: Thanks bhai, it helped

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Data Entry Events are only triggered when a contact goes from a state of not meeting criteria to then meeting the criteria. Since the same contact that had already met criteria was updated, the event was not triggered.

See link here:

"When a record is updated, the rule runs only if the record meets rule criteria after the update. The rule does not run when a record that previously met rule criteria is updated."

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5